# How to determine line equation, given plane and direction

Tags: math, equation, direction, plane

A line L lies on the plane: x + y + z + 1 = 0, the line direction is (a, 1,0) for some value
a ∈ ℝ:

I don't know how to answer this questions, would appreciate your help:

1. Can we determine the line equation from the given details above? How many possible lines exist?
2. If the line also passes through the point (1, −1, −1), can we determine the line equation? How many lines exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If point `(x0, y0, z0)` belongs to the plane, then point `(x0 + a , y0 + 1, z0)` should belong to this plane too, so

```
x0 + a + y0 + 1 + z0 = 1
(x0 + y0 + z0) + a + 1 = 1
1 + a + 1 = 1
a = -1
```

Another way - line belonging the plane must be perpendicular to the plane normal, so dot product of normal and direction vector must be zero:

```
1 * a + 1 * 1 + 1 * 0  = 0
a = -1
```

We know only direction vector, there is infinite number of parallel lines in given plane.

If we fix one point, we can get unique line

```
base =  (1, −1, −1)
dir  =  (-1, 1, 0)
L = (1, −1, −1) + t * (-1, 1, 0)
```

This is parametric equation of the line